# Change a date field to the last day of the previous month in SQL

Tags: sql, date

I have a date field in my database which I need to change to the last day of the previous month. Currently, all dates in this field are dated the first of the month. I know I can do this using a case statement, however, I know there has to be an easier way of doing this.

This is also a date time field if that makes a difference.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What database system do you use? postgresql, sqlserver, oracle, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL SERVER you can do it like this:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE 
SET MYDATEFIELD = DATEADD(DAY,-1,MYDATEFIELD);
```

In Oracle it should just be:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE 
SET MYDATEFIELD = MYDATEFIELD - 1;
```

Every major database should have something pretty similar

Comment: Does it matter if it is a date time field?

Comment: No it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

```
update your_table
set column_date=DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(month,(MONTH(@date)-1),DATEADD(year,Year(column_date)-1900,0)))
```